# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_1' (type Functional)

Tags: error-handling, lstm

I have been trying to run this code
`history = model.fit(x_train, y_train ,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs ,validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)`

but it is not works and shows this error. How can I do?

### Epoch 1/15

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train ,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs ,validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 235, in assert_input_compatibility
    

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_1' (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "time_distributed" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 10, 128, 128)

Call arguments received by layer 'model_1' (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 10, 128, 128), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

Before I use this code I has been tried to run LSTM+VGG 16. it has been passed already. the code shows below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed
#from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
timesteps = 10
num_classes = 2
video = Input(shape=(timesteps,128,128,3))
base_model = VGG16(input_shape=(128,128,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

base_model.trainable = False

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
print(base_model.summary())
print("---------------------------")
cnn = Model(base_model.input, cnn_out)
print(cnn.summary())
print("---------------------------")
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1)(encoded_frames)
hidden_Drop = Dropout(0.1)(encoded_sequence)
hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
hidden_layer = Flatten()(hidden_layer)
outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
model = Model([video], outputs)

model.summary()
plot_model(base_model, to_file='modelvgg16base_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
plot_model(model, to_file='modelvgg16_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy'
                , metrics=["accuracy"])

batch_size = 32
epochs = 15
```